# Grammar for following JAVA predicates

Tags: java, antlr

I'm trying to write productions ( LL ) for the following code

```
a[i].b[a[p]].id.xyz.a[c].o = i;
```

Using ASTView in Eclipse, the productions are like

```
FieldAccess -> Exp NAME
Exp -> FieldAccess
FieldAccess -> ArrayAccess NAME
ArrayAccess -> ArrayAccess Exp
ArrayAccess -> FieldAccess 
Exp -> FieldAccess
.....
```

How can I define the above in Antlr? They are left recursive and as far as I know JAVA is LL.

Comment: After you can parse these, what do you intend to do?

Comment: @IraBaxter - static analysis

Comment: You need lots more than parsing to do that.  See my essay on Life After Parsing: http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to create an ANTLR v3 grammar for the rules:

```
FieldAccess -> Exp NAME
Exp         -> FieldAccess
```

ANTLR v4 *can* handle left recursion, but only *direct left recursive rules*:

```
Exp -> Exp '*' Exp
     | Exp '/' Exp
     | Exp '+' Exp
     ...
     | Name
     ...
```

*(pseudo grammar syntax!)*

but v4 is also *not* able to cope with your ***in**direct left recursive rules*:

```
FieldAccess -> Exp NAME
Exp         -> FieldAccess
```

I'm pretty sure you can make ANTLR create an AST just as Eclipse does using some fancy AST rewrite rules, but then you'll have edit your question and "draw" (or post a picture) of the desired AST for the input `a[i].b[a[p].x].id.xyz.a[c].o = i;`, and I might have a stab at it.

### EDIT

Here's a small demo of how to parse your example input in a similar AST as you posted:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  ASSIGN;
  IND;
  FA;
}

parse
 : assign EOF -> assign
 ;

assign
 : lookup '=' expr ';' -> ^(ASSIGN lookup expr)
 ;

expr
 : lookup
 ;

lookup
 : (NAME -> NAME) ( array_index  -> ^(IND $lookup array_index)
                  | field_access -> ^(FA $lookup field_access)
                  )*
 ;

array_index
 : '[' expr ']' -> expr
 ;

field_access
 : '.' NAME -> NAME
 ;

NAME  : 'a'..'z'+;
SPACE : ' ' {skip();};
```

WHen I debug the parser in ANTLRWorks with the input `a[i].b[a[p].x].id.xyz.a[c].o = i;`, the following AST is being generated:

[image]

### EDIT

The rule:

```
lookup
 : (NAME -> NAME) ( array_index  -> ^(IND $lookup array_index)
                  | field_access -> ^(FA $lookup field_access)
                  )*
 ;
```

is nothing more than this:

```
lookup
 : NAME ( array_index^
        | field_access^
        )*
 ;
```

except the first will, for the input `"a[i].b"`, create an AST like this:

```
        FA
       /  \
     IND   B
     / \
    A   I
```

where the latter would create a "reversed" AST:

```
        FA
       /  \
      B   IND
          / \
         I   A
```

(of course, the `FA` and `IND` wouldn't be in the last AST because they're not in the `array_index` and `field_access` rules, but if you'd put them there, it would have that structure).

Comment: @questions, it's just like any other (new) thing you learn: practice, practice & practice. :)

Comment: @questions Terence's (creator of ANTLR) books are great, and Scott Stanchfield has some very nice video tutorials, all of them mentioned in this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278480/antlr-tutorials

Comment: Thanks! I dont want to have extended discussion in comments, but can you please add in your answer a litte about `lookup` production. What does `$lookup` mean in two `|` cases?

Comment: @questions, I just saw you last comment: will edit my answer later today with an explanation of `$lookup`.